# Using Jenkins and/or Ant, how can I rename a directory after a build step?

Tags: java, svn, jenkins, ant

I am managing a java build process in Jenkins and after a number of projects are built I want to rename the distribution/release folder with something like the SVN revision number.

I can probably do this in a shell script from jenkins, but can I do it in the Ant config/build file as well?  I think I can populate the env vars with the svn/jenkins details, but I don;t know how to reference those from an ant xml build file

For example, after I do a build I have something like:

> /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MyProject/dist/

which contains a bunch of stuff that was packaged.
I'd like to rename the leaf directory 'dist' to something like 'release.x' or even 'release.datetime'

Alternatively, what is considered best practice int he java world as far as "labeling" builds after they are done so one can tell them apart and manage them for release mgmt activities?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out to be pretty simple - though I did not rename, rather I named the dist directory when i create it.  here is the relevant bit in the ant build file:

```
> ... <property environment="env"/>  <property name="dist" 
> location="dist.${env.SVN_REVISION}"/>
```

Jenkins publishes the env vars when it spawns the ant tasks.  I will probably come up with a better naming scheme, but this is the first step in making unique distributions/versions.